# pivot longer into two columns

Tags: dataframe, ggplot2, pivot

I am trying to use pivot_longer to turn 8 columns into two columns. I have means for 4 variables and standard deviations for the same 4 variables. I want to pivot_longer the dataframe to have a column named Means and a column named sd, each with the means and sd across years for the 4 variables. This is so I can plot how the variable means change through the years and to plot their sd as well

I tried doing two pivot longer but did not work:

```
df <- groupedMel2 %>% pivot_longer( cols= c("meanHBrit","meanFBrit", "meanHEu","meanFEu"), names_to="Meanval",values_to= "Mean")
df<- df %>% pivot_longer( cols= c("sdHBrit","sdFBrit", "sdHEu","sdFEu"), names_to="SdVal",values_to= "Sd")
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Year, y=Mean)) + geom_line(aes(colour=Meanval))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Mean- Sd, ymax = Mean + Sd), alpha = 0.1)+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1))))) +
  labs(y="traits")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using `pivot_longer` followed by `pivot_wider`.

First creating some data

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~meanHBrit, ~meanFBrit, ~sdHBrit, ~sdFBrit,
  2021, 2, 1.1, 0.14, 0.13,
  2022, 5.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.11,
  2023, 4, 4, 0.5, 0.55
)
```

Now pivoting to a longer form, then widening the "stat" variable into two columns:

```
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-year,
               names_to = c('stat', 'trait'),
               names_pattern = '(mean|sd)(.*)') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'stat',
              values_from = 'value')
df
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>    year trait  mean    sd
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2021 HBrit   2    0.14
#> 2  2021 FBrit   1.1  0.13
#> 3  2022 HBrit   5.5  0.5 
#> 4  2022 FBrit   0.9  0.11
#> 5  2023 HBrit   4    0.5 
#> 6  2023 FBrit   4    0.55
```

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trait)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), alpha = 0.1) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1))))) +
  labs(y="traits")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>